# Html Checkbox Disabled State is Difficult to Read

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styling

I have a checkbox created as follows:

```
<td class="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsBusinessHours)</td>
```

It renders as the following html:

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="check-box" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked"/>
```

My problem is that the check in the box is very hard to read in this disabled state.

I would like to know the best way to style the checkbox to make it appear like the non-disabled checkbox (or otherwise make it more readable).  However I still want the checkbox to be read only.

My project uses Asp.Net MVC, jQuery and jQuery-UI.

Comment: Which browser are you using, and on which OS? Can you post screen shots of the difference you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue by replacing my checkboxes with jQuery UI buttons.  The jQuery script that I ended up using is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058609/jquery-ui-button-set-initial-icon).

Answer (score 0):

you can add rules like this to you CSS style sheet :

```
input[disabled='disabled'] {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

but ie6 doesnt support that, just a heads up.