# jQuery-UI Button Set Initial Icon

Tags: jquery-ui, button, checkbox, icons

I have the following jQuery script to transform a checkbox into a jQuery-UI button and set up the icons to be displayed.  It also changes the icon when the button is clicked.  It all works fine.  However I cannot seem to hit on the correct syntax to set the initial icon based on the initial checked state of the checkbox.

```
function setCheckBoxImages() {
        $(".check-box-image").button({
            icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' },
            text: false
        }).change(function () {
            $(this).button("option", {
                icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : '' }
            });
        });
    };

<input class="check-box-image" type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsBusinessHours" id="checkbox1" disabled/><label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

EDIT:
Here is my final working markup and script as per accidentalgenius answer below:

```
@Html.CheckBox(@cbMobileId, @item.IsMobile, new { @class = "check-box-image", disabled = "disabled" })<label for="@cbMobileId">    

function setCheckBoxImages() {
        var checkboxes= $(".check-box-image");

        checkboxes.button({
            text: false
        }).change(function () {
            $(this).button("option", {
                icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : 'ui-icon-minus' }
            });
        });

        checkboxes.each(function () {
            $(this).change();
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all of the jQuery Buttons and call the change function for each one.

Comment: Have put the final script that I used in the original question above.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `setCheckBoxImages()`? Without seeing the rest of the code it is hard, but try calling it on `document.ready`.

You should be setting the initial icons based on the status of the checkbox:

```
function setCheckBoxImages() {
        var check = $(".check-box-image");
        check.button({
            icons: { primary: check.is(':checked') ? 'ui-icon-check' : '' },
            text: false
        }).change(function () {
            $(this).button("option", {
                icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : '' }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: I've added some code to my answer. I'm basically applying the same verification during the button construction.

Comment: I have just tried your code and it is not working for me.  All "check boxes" still show up with the 'ui-icon-check' icon - regardless of whether they are checked or not.

Comment: I notice that the "check" variable contains an array of check boxes (all the ones that match the specified class).  Is this why the code is not working?

Comment: If it is an array, you need to loop it like you did in your final edit.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your function has not been called.
try this on your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check-box-image").button({
        icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-check' },
        text: false
    }).change(function () {
        $(this).button("option", {
            icons: { primary: this.checked ? 'ui-icon-check' : '' }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am already calling this script in the document.ready function.

Comment: Okay, I think your code on your post has no error. I copy and paste your code in my html file and it's working. maybe there's error on your other javascript code so your code isn't working. Check it!